# pUnkSite->QueryInterface(IID_IOleWindow) fails with E_NOINTERFACE in my BHO

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, com, bho, queryinterface

I use Microsoft Visual C++ and Windows 7.
I am developing IE toolbar with ATL and MFC. IE version is 11.0.9600.17420.

First of all, I have created COM object implementing `IDeskBand` and `IObjectWithSite` interfaces.
Second, I have implemented `IDeskBand` methods and `IObjectWithSite::SetSite` method. It takes only one parameter, `IUnknown *pUnkSite`.

As I remember, I can do `pUnkSite->QueryInterface(IID_IOleWindow, (void**)&pOleWindow);` to get IOleWindow interface from site, and then I can call `pOleWindow->GetWindow(&hWnd);` to get parent window handle; so I can create my toolbar window as a child of window with this `hWnd`.

So I did it and realized that `pUnkSite->QueryInterface(IID_IOleWindow, (void**)&pOleWindow);` returns `0x80004002` which is `E_NOINTERFACE` error, so `IOleWindow` is not implemented by `pUnkSite` object! I opened IE in debugger, loaded symbols, traced to `QISearch` and realized that there is no implementation of `IOleWindow` interface. If I am not mistaken it was `CIEFrameAuto` interface.

So, how can I obtain `IOleWindow` interface for parent window for my toolbar?

Comment: Is it a BHO, or a toolbar? The title says the former, but the content the latter. How did you register your object? See also: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776819.aspx

Comment: @IgorTandetnik OK, now I register it only on HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Toolbar and not as BHO. But my `SetSite()` method is not called now!

Comment: Newly registered toolbars are off by default. Right-click the title of IE window, see if your toolbar shows up in the menu. If so, enable it there.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik i did it of course. It waits some time then asks if I want to disable this extension. Toolbar name is showed in the context menu. No `OutputDebugString()` in `SetSite()` nor `__asm int 3` after debug string output happen.

Comment: Well, you must be doing something wrong, but it's hard to see what without seeing the code. Try to figure out where the process fails. Does your DLL get loaded? Is `DllGetClassObject` called? Is `IClassFactory::CreateInstance` called, and if so, which interface is being requested? Is `QueryInterface` called on the object that `CreateInstance` creates, and if so, which interfaces are being queried?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik DLL gets loaded. `DllGetClassObject` is called. `IClassFactory::CreateInstance()` is called - and it queries `IDeskBand2`, right, it is not implemented. In which version of IE it started to create `IDeskBand2` instance instead of `IDeskBand`?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik also I want my toolbar to be compatible with all IE version starting with IE7. Is it enough to implement `IDeskBand2` interface only?

Comment: Seeing is `IDeskBand2` derives from `IDeskBand`, you would necessarily implement both anyway. As to which version started requiring `IDeskBand2` - no idea, sorry. I last implemented an IE toolbar circa 2005, when IE6 was the new shiny.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik thank you. All is working perfect now.